# Web.Config <appSettings file=""> question

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined in my web.config the following:

```
<appSettings file="settings.config" >
</appSettings>
```

It works just fine, but my question is, how to i modify it at runtime?

If i use:

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

This actually modifies my web.config.

I have a few entries in my custom configuration file i would like to edit.

Any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Never. Edit. The. Web.Config programmatically.

Comment: OP isn't asking to do that - the appSettings have been moved to an external config file, meaning application resets won't occur if these values are changed on the fly. This is reasonable.

Comment: By default, it will restart. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228057(VS.80).aspx Regardless you should still never programmatically edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give virtual path to your external config file. So it would be something like

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/settings");
var appSettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
```

or

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/settings.config");
var appSettings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
```

Further, restartOnExternalChanges attribute on the section element would control if application would restart on configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks guys went with a different approach.